# CoreData concurrency debugger stops executeFetchRequest with EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

I’m using `-com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1` to find any CoreData concurrency issues in my app. I’ve come across an issue where it stops on `executeFetchRequest`:

```
    __block NSArray *results = nil;
    [context performBlockAndWait:^{

        NSError *error = nil;

        results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

        if (results == nil) 
        {
            [MagicalRecord handleErrors:error];
        }

    }];
    return results;
```

This is from within the [MagicalRecord library](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/blob/b83b159ca092fdf0dc614957b91e0e00f18169eb/MagicalRecord/Categories/NSManagedObject/NSManagedObject%2BMagicalRecord.m#L47). I am running an older version, but I think my issue is with my code, not MagicalRecord.

And the error it provides is:

```
 Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
```

I’m using MagicalRecord's default context and I am on the main thread. And all the objects in my predicate are from the default context as well:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"form == %@ AND id <> 0 AND user == %@", self, user];
```

I *assume* there is probably some side effect happening else where in the code, but I don’t know where else to look. To reproduce the issue I’m:

1. Opening a new view controller
2. Tap the cancel button
3. The method that handles the action deletes an object (which I’ve commented out and it still triggers the issue) and then it calls a delegate method.
4. That delegate method reloads the table and dismisses the presented controller.
5. When reloading the table, it calls `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` which contains the query which triggers the issue.

The first time the table loads, there isn’t a problem with the query. Only after opening the new view and hitting cancel.

There is another set of steps that also runs into this problem so I’m really not sure what is causing it.

How do I debug what the side effect might be? Or, if the problem is with the fetch request, what is the problem with it?

Are there any tools to help diagnose what/where the issue is?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Here is the full back trace:

```
    #0  0x0000000110630a14 in +[NSManagedObjectContext __Multithreading_Violation_AllThatIsLeftToUsIsHonor__] ()
    #1  0x0000000110600856 in -[_PFBatchFaultingArray count] ()
    #2  0x000000011097d4fe in +[NSSet setWithArray:] ()
    #3  0x000000011057b680 in -[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:] ()
    #4  0x000000010b043242 in __67+[NSManagedObject(MagicalRecord) MR_executeFetchRequest:inContext:]_block_invoke at /Users/.../ios/External/MagicalRecord/Categories/NSManagedObject/NSManagedObject+MagicalRecord.m:52
    #5  0x00000001105c2127 in developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform ()
    #6  0x00000001105c1fee in -[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:] ()
    #7  0x000000010b04308f in +[NSManagedObject(MagicalRecord) MR_executeFetchRequest:inContext:] at /Users/.../ios/External/MagicalRecord/Categories/NSManagedObject/NSManagedObject+MagicalRecord.m:48
    #8  0x000000010b0434fa in +[NSManagedObject(MagicalRecord) MR_executeFetchRequestAndReturnFirstObject:inContext:] at /Users/.../ios/External/MagicalRecord/Categories/NSManagedObject/NSManagedObject+MagicalRecord.m:75
    #9  0x000000010b128939 in +[NSManagedObject(MagicalFinders) MR_findFirstWithPredicate:sortedBy:ascending:inContext:] at /Users/.../ios/External/MagicalRecord/Categories/NSManagedObject/NSManagedObject+MagicalFinders.m:183
    #10 0x000000010b08c066 in -[FormStructure lastInspectionByUser:] at /Users/.../ios/Sources/Models/Mogenerator/FormStructure.m:29
    #11 0x000000010b08c0fe in -[FormStructure hasDraftByUser:] at /Users/.../ios/Sources/Models/Mogenerator/FormStructure.m:34
    #12 0x000000010b0d56ac in -[FormsViewController configureCell:atIndexPath:] at /Users/.../ios/Sources/ViewControllers/MainApp/Inspections/FormsViewController.m:193
    #13 0x000000010b0d537e in -[FormsViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] at /Users/.../ios/Sources/ViewControllers/MainApp/Inspections/FormsViewController.m:173
    #14 0x000000010e6164f4 in -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] ()
    #15 0x000000010e61662c in -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] ()
    #16 0x000000010e5ead4f in -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] ()
    #17 0x000000010e61f686 in -[UITableView _performWithCachedTraitCollection:] ()
    #18 0x000000010e606344 in -[UITableView layoutSubviews] ()
    #19 0x000000010e573980 in -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] ()
    #20 0x000000010e1f9c00 in -[CALayer layoutSublayers] ()
    #21 0x000000010e1ee08e in CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) ()
    #22 0x000000010e1edf0c in CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) ()
    #23 0x000000010e1e23c9 in CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) ()
    #24 0x000000010e210086 in CA::Transaction::commit() ()
    #25 0x000000010e4e519b in _afterCACommitHandler ()
    #26 0x0000000110958c37 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ ()
    #27 0x0000000110958ba7 in __CFRunLoopDoObservers ()
    #28 0x000000011094e7fb in __CFRunLoopRun ()
    #29 0x000000011094e0f8 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
    #30 0x0000000113885ad2 in GSEventRunModal ()
    #31 0x000000010e4b8f09 in UIApplicationMain ()
    #32 0x000000010b07539f in main at /Users/.../ios/Sources/Application/main.m:14
    #33 0x000000011149b92d in start ()
    #34 0x000000011149b92d in start ()
```

Comment: I encountered the same error and +/- the same stack trace with iOS 10.3.2; How did you handle it finally?

Comment: Shoot. It has been awhile. I don't remember what I ended up doing for this. Probably using a different block to get the context.